# Appending bytes using Amazon S3 .Net SDK

Tags: c#, amazon-s3

I have the following piece of code which works great for a simple file upload. But let's say I wanted to append to an existing file or simply upload random chunks of bytes, like the first and last 10 bytes? Is this even possible with the official SDK?

```
PutObjectRequest request = new PutObjectRequest();

FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"C:\myFolder\MyFile.bin", FileMode.Open);
request.WithInputStream(fs);
request.WithBucketName(bucketName);
request.WithKey(keyName);
client.PutObject(request);
fs.Close();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no way to append data to existing objects in S3. You have to overwrite the entire file.

Although, in saying that, it is possible to a degree with [Amazon's large file](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/index.html?UsingMPDotNetAPI.html) support. With this uploads are broken into chunks and reassembled on S3. But you have to do it as part of a single transfer and its only for large files.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Will look into your link.

Comment: Modifying already uploaded objects is however possible with Windows Azure Storage, using block and page blobs.

Comment: @fabrizioM - yes, you can't append data to existing files in S3.

Answer (score 4):

This previous answer appears to no longer be the case.  You can currently manage an append like process by using an existing object as the initial part of a multi-part upload.  Then delete the previous object when done transferring.

See:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/CopyingObjctsUsingLLNetMPUapi.html

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/mpUploadUploadPartCopy.html